# Airflow scheduler stops after few hours

Tags: linux, multi-processor

I am running 3-4  python DAGs.The issue is that the scheduler goes down after 4-5 hours. When i start it, it runs fine and DAGs do run, but after few hours it goes down with following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/airflow", line 28, in 
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 882, in scheduler
    job.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 200, in run
    self._execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1312, in _execute
    self._execute_helper(processor_manager)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1409, in _execute_helper
    simple_dags = processor_manager.heartbeat()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/dag_processing.py", line 622, in heartbeat
    processor = self._processor_factory(file_path, log_file_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1301, in processor_factory
    log_file_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 257, in **init**
    self._result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/**init**.py", line 218, in Queue
    return Queue(maxsize)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 63, in **init**
    self._rlock = Lock()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 147, in **init**
    SemLock.**init**(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 75, in **init**
    sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(kind, value, maxvalue)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I have aready changed /dev/shm directory permissions to 1777 and added this into path bind variable. My machine is 8 core Azure VM. Python version is 2.7.5.

Please guide.

Comment: what kind of scheduler do you use?